# 12.04 - Problem with Update Manager

Tags: update-manager

When opening up Update Manager, I get the following message -

Could not initialize the package information

```
E:Type 'b-src' is not a known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/whatsapp-purple-ppa-precise.list,

E:The list of sources could not be read, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Please help.

---

Output for ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

```
cdemu-ppa-precise.list.bak
cdemu-ppa-precise.list.save
getdeb.list
getdeb.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
kalakris-okular-precise.list
kalakris-okular-precise.list.save
kubuntu-ppa-backports-precise.list
kubuntu-ppa-backports-precise.list.save
linrunner-tlp-precise.list
linrunner-tlp-precise.list.save
nilarimogard-webupd8-precise.list
nilarimogard-webupd8-precise.list.save
nvbn-rm-ppa-precise.list
nvbn-rm-ppa-precise.list.save
opera.list
opera.list.save
precise-dell.list
precise-dell.list.save
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_fragment_ubuntu.list
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_fragment_ubuntu.list.save
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_steam_ubuntu.list
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_steam_ubuntu.list.save
scopes-packagers-ppa-precise.list
scopes-packagers-ppa-precise.list.save
skunk-pepper-flash-precise.list
skunk-pepper-flash-precise.list.save
springseed.list
springseed.list.save
steam.list
steam.list.save
teejee2008-ppa-precise.list
teejee2008-ppa-precise.list.save
ubuntu-extras.list
ubuntu-extras.list.save
ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list
ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list.save
videolan-stable-daily-precise.list
videolan-stable-daily-precise.list.save
webupd8team-jupiter-precise.list
webupd8team-jupiter-precise.list.save
webupd8team-tor-browser-precise.list
webupd8team-tor-browser-precise.list.save
webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-precise.list
webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-precise.list.save
whatsapp-purple-ppa-precise.list
whatsapp-purple-ppa-precise.list.save
```

Comment: What is the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/whatsapp-purple-ppa-precise.list`? Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in whatsapp purleppa, Remove it and you'll be alright.

```
sudo rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/whatsapp-purple-ppa-precise.list
sudo rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/whatsapp-purple-ppa-precise.list.save
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: The following message appears -  rm: cannot remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/whatsapp-purle-ppa-precise.list': No such file or directory

Comment: My brother had tried to install the following plugin - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:whatsapp-purple/ppa
, sudo apt-get update
, sudo apt-get install pidgin-whatsapp

Comment: what is the output of the command `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: It's - ls: cannot access etc/apt/sources.list.d/: No such file or directory

Comment: please just copy paste commands `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` you miss / before etc

Comment: I have edited the question to show the output.

Comment: Check the edit now

Comment: @PrashantSingh So what happens?

Comment: It's - rm: cannot remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/whatsapp-purle-ppa-precise.list': No such file or directory ,  rm: cannot remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/whatsapp-purle-ppa-precise.list.save': No such file or directory

Comment: You missed a "p" in "purple". Please try again.

Comment: @PrashantSingh Please just copy paste, you miss p in purple

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I had lost my internet for a while there so could not reply back promptly.

Comment: @PrashantSingh you are welcome

Answer (score -1):

You could try this enter in the terminal:

```
rm -r /etc/atp/sources.d /etc/atp/sources.list
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: -1 This would remove all other third party repositories. This is a very bad idea